# Star Rating For a Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I created a custom post type for Testimonials, added author name as custom metabox field. Next I want to add a star rating for each of my Testimonial posts.

[image: Screenshot of placeholder Testimonial with star rating]

So I need this feature like if the post has 5 stars I can set 5 stars on the Testimonial Edit screen as a metabox or custom field.

Comment: just added dropdown with 1 to 5 value and set the value in backend.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a plugin like https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ for this, or create a custom meta box with a input field for the number of stars, with a [plugin](https://metabox.io/how-to-create-custom-meta-boxes-custom-fields-in-wordpress/) or in your [theme](https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-custom-meta-boxes-to-wordpress/)

Personally I would always use the advancedcustomfields plugin for this, because this allows you to create multiple custom fields with validation without a lot of coding.

Comment: Thanks. But i need to do it without plugin

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can add the dropdown for rating using meta boxes and based on the metabox value you can display the number of stars.